# How can I replace like operator in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am a beginner in cassandra DB. in mysql you can use like operator.
For example if I want to to filter names of all those people who have "Michael" in their full name.
How can I perform it in Cassandra?

The output should be like

"Michael Jackson"
"Kamraan Micheal"
"Michael kern"

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Cassandra is a key based data store -- this kind of problem is resolved by putting a full text search engine beside Cassandra (like solr/elastic search) -- Datastax enterprise offers the solution described using solr. HTH, Carlo

Comment: Thank You! it is real helpful.